How can any object except Plasma emit white light or be a blackbody--it seems contradictory?
How can any physical object absorb and emit white light when all objects are made from atoms and molecules, each of which has its own absorption/emissions spectrum that acts as it's signature “chemical fingerprint”? Showing a continuous spectrum seems contradictory to the concept of an object being made of atoms. What am I not understanding here?
In fact, the only time I can see that a blackbody could exist is when the object is so hot that it becomes plasma with free electrons, where the electrons can acquire a continuous range of energies and therefore emit a continuous spectrum.
In a related idea, can atoms/molecules absorb or emit light in any other way than electrons being bumped up or falling down from their known quantized energy levels? Maybe I am not taking this into consideration?
What am I missing in my understanding?

When many atoms come together, they interact. These interactions prevent the total system wave function from being a simple product of single-atom wave functions. The energy spectrum also changes. In addition you can get electromagnetic effects, spin-orbit coupling etc. that smears out the energy spectrum further.

Finally, black bodies are theoretical idealizations where no constituents exists. True emission/absorption spectra never match the ideal spectrum.

First, black body radiation is an idealisation.
Further, a collection of atoms of the same type radiate some frequencies more than other frequencies, but they also absorb these frequencies more than other frequencies. When the free path of this radiation is much smaller than the size of the collection of atoms, then the preference for these frequencies in both radiating and absorbing cancel each other.

What is missing is the higher order processes/effects. When talking about "chemical fingerprint" we mean the most intensive absorption/emission lines. In reality there are many processes, like Raman scattering, two-photon absorption and emission, etc., which couple radiative modes of different energies. The energy is thus pumped between the modes till equilibrium is established between them (i.e., microscopic balance between the forward and the reverse process.) Note that statistical physics always comes with a caveat that we wait a sufficiently long time for thermodynamic equilibrium to establish. It is only when the sufficiently long turns out longer than the duration of the experiment or the lifetime of the universe or another important scale that we speak of ergodicity breaking, etc. - this situations happen all the time, but typically not for gases (definite polarization of magnets is the most obvious example.)
Note also that even in a non-plasma gas the spectrum lines have natural linewidth and are also Doppler-shifted, depending on the direction where the atom/molecule flies (this is used with a great effect in laser cooling.)
On the other hand, metals are indeed very close to plasma - as the state of their electrons is even termed electron plasma, and these electrons do undergo effects like Bremsstrahlung.
Related
How is light emitted by an incandescent lamp?
Difference in thermal radiation between condensed matter and gases
How does radiation become black-body radiation?
Understanding thermal radiation in a conductor, gas and insulator
How do photons reach thermal equilibrium with the walls of the blackbody cavity?
Quantum and non-equilibrium properties of the radiation, emitted by "thermal light sources"

Thank you for this explanation above.   Here is what I now have come to believe--please let me know if I am correct?
My deduction:  Since Blackbody Radiation is dependent on the Temperature alone, and since different objects are made up of different molecules, the main emitter of blackbody radiation from any object of a certain temperature would be the vibrational, translational, and rotational movement of the molecules, and not the "emission spectrum" which would give a "fingerprint" of the chemical makeup of the substance.

Thank you, but still confused, so a few more questions:
Since Blackbody radiation given off by an object is etermined by it's Temperature, at a molecular level, what is the Temperature doing to alter this raditaion curve--I know higher Temperatures are causing the atoms/molecules of the object to vibrate, rotate, translate faster than at a lower Temperature of the same object.   Is this faster movement enough to give off radiation wihtout electrons transitioning energy levels (and if so, how?)  or is ER radiation given off only when electrons drop from higher to lower energy levels?   Thanks
